# typescript custom .d.ts import module does not work

Tags: typescript, module

I have the following .d.ts file

```
interface MyInterface {
    login();
    logout();
}

declare module "myOtherModule" {
    export = MyInterface
}
```

Now in my .ts file I include the following

```
import { MyInterface } from '../modules/myOtherModule';
```

Here I get the error "myOtherModule.d.ts" is not a module.  Shouldn't this work? if not how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, try using in your **`myOtherModule.d.ts`** file:

```
export interface MyInterface {
  login();
  logout();
}
```

And your **`foo.ts`** file:

```
import { MyInterface } from '../modules/myOtherModule';
```

Please refer to the official TypeScript templates for writing .d.ts files.

You can find some examples here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates.html

There is a lot of useful information in these templates if you want to write a .d.ts file for a custom module or a class-module.

Also, there are a lot of useful information in here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/deep-dive.html

Comment: Hi thanks for this, however I am not in a position to change the .d.ts file since this is a third party file.